# Javascript obje.key is undefined when assigned to object itself

Tags: javascript

I was looking at a snippet from [here](https://h5bp.github.io/Front-end-Developer-Interview-Questions/)

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

When I log foo.x it says undefined.
Why's it so? I expected it to be {n: 2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are assigned from left to right so this is what happens:

```
foo.x = {n: 2};
```

which results in foo being `{n: 1, x: {n: 2}}`

then foo is being assigned a new value

```
foo = {n: 2};
```

which overrides it to `{n: 2}`.

Comment: But assignment associates right-to-left: `foo.x = foo = {n: 2};` is equivalent to `foo.x = (foo = {n: 2});` and `(foo.x = foo) = {n: 2};` throws.

Comment: Wow. Both your explanations seem valid but I am now confused what's the right flow. Can someone sort this. I see @AndrewSvietlichnyy answer more justifiable

Comment: I think his answer is the correct one, but it results in the behavior I explained

Answer (score 0):

The value of `foo.x` is evaluated before both assignments, so it refers to `x` property of the old `foo` object. This behavior is defined by 12.14.4 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation ([ES6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), [latest draft](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators)) which tells us that left side of assignment operator (assignment target) must be evaluated before right side of assignment operator (assigned value).

So these three have the same result:

```js
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
console.log(foo, bar)
```

```js
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
bar.x = foo = {n: 2};
console.log(foo, bar)
```

```js
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = (foo = {n: 2});
console.log(foo, bar)
```